# what is the Postgre equivalent data type for mysql YEAR data type

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

we are migrating data from mysql to Postgre.
what is the equivalent data type in Postgre for Mysql YEAR data type.

Comment: Create one yourself: `CREATE DOMAIN year AS SMALLINT;` If you need more logic in it, like converting the value 77 to 1977 or so, you could create a TYPE.